# Newline in ionicpopup content

Tags: popup, ionic-framework

Is it possible to have a newline character in ionicpopup content?

I am trying to do this:

```
  $ionicPopup.alert({
                  title: 'Now what?',
                  content: "To start receiving messages: \n"
                           + "        - Open the side menu (button on top left) \n"
                           + "   - Tap 'Add Organisations' \n"
                           + "   - Browse the list of organisations available \n" 
                           + "or \n"
                           + "   - Enter a Passphrase to join a private group. \n \n"
                           + "Once you've subscribed to an organisation, you'll start receiving messages from them.",
                  buttons: [
                            { text: "Don't show me again" },
                            {
                              text: 'Okay',
                              type: 'button-positive'
                            }
                          ]
                }).then(function(res) {
                  if(res) {
                        console.log('You are sure');
                  } else {
                    console.log('You are not sure');
                  }
            });
```

My newline characters are not working. I see the content in the popup as one long paragraph without new lines.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes it is possible to have newline character in ionic popup content.

Replace **\n** with **< br >** tag and it works. The ionic framework outputs HTML after execution of that javascript. It also works with html string single quotation string.

Comment: Thank you I didn't know I could put html elements in there. Slip up on my side with not reading proper docs!

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  Can anyone confirm that this still works?

Comment: It works, but you have to put <br> tag infront of the message you'd like. i.e.

template: 'Message: ' + error.message  + '<br>Your custom text?'

Answer (score 0):

you can use break like below

```
strMessage:any;
strEmpName:any;


strMessage: 'Hi Team,'+'<br\><br\> Please find the Employee Name'+'<br\><br\>' + this.strEmpName+'<br\><br\>'+'Thanks & Regards'+'<br\>'+'Rakesh Jha';

this.emailComposer.open({
  app: 'gmail',
  to: 'abc@gmail.com',
  cc: ['xyz@gmail.com', 'rkj@gmail.com.com'],
  bcc: ['pqr@ttt.com', 'rkj@ttt.com'],
  body: 'Hi Team,'+'<br\><br\> Please find the Employee Name'+'<br\><br\>' + this.strEmpName+'<br\><br\>'+'Thanks & Regards'+'<br\>'+'Rakesh Jha';
  isHtml: true,
});
```

Hope this work for you.